# Deploy AWS serverless application with assumerole using visual studio tookit

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-serverless, aws-toolkit

I know how to publish a serverless application using aws visual studio toolkit.

It's just you login into aws explorer with user's access key & Secret access key. and then right click on the solution and publish to AWS lambda. It's so simple.

But what about if i have my user has a different assume role that further has access to all the AWS resources and can publish.

So i know how to publish it using assume role via aws CLI by creating a profile let's say "powerdevrole" and whenever we type any command deploy then we use "--profile powerdevrole" in the end with MFA access enabled.

So my question is how to publish the same using aws toolkit if we have an assume role and MFA enabled on that??

Also i have tried to get the cached keys and then used that into aws explorer to publish my project but it's not working for me.

Please help me out.

Thanks,
Vinod Bhatt

Comment: I just ran into this same issue.  Seems stupid not to support such an obvious need. My faith in AWS just dropped a bit.